# Upload an array of images to coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When i needed to upload just one image to coredata , i just had one entity restaurants with an image field,

Then when i needed to upload multiple images , i created another entity called images with fields, image and id, id field is also there in restaurants,

Now if the user wants to use the multiple images of restaurants, i use opalimagepicker to select multiple images and then get back an array of `var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()`

For single image the code was very simple i just display the image in an UIImageView and then use the same to upload to core data as below

```
if let restaurantImage = cell5.imageToUpload.image {
          restaurant.image = restaurantImage.pngData()
        }
```

But now i want multiple images to be store in image entity with each image corresponding to same id , ie id of user like below

image1 - abc

image2 - abc

So again, i know how to upload single image in one entity model but how to upload array of images in multiple entity model

But i do not know the coredata way to do it , can any one point me to a useful way to solve it , thanks, my relationship model is attached

Also there is still an image field in restaurants entity, how to adjust that ?

[image]

UPADTE - so i am able to save the array of images in coredata restaurant entity using this. using @danielson guidance

```
for image in arrayOfImages {
          print("saved")
          restaurant.image = image.pngData()
        }
```

But as in other database i cannot use select statement to see how data was saved , i do not have any way to find how exactly this was done,

also how can i extract say the second image from array, currently as there is just one image , i am doing this , this for fetching the data from core data and showing it , but how i show a certain image from array now ?

```
if let restaurantImage = restaurant.image {
                     cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
                   }
```

UPDATE

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Restaurant {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Restaurant> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Restaurant>(entityName: "Restaurant")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var image: Data?
    @NSManaged public var isVisited: Bool
    @NSManaged public var location: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var phone: String?
    @NSManaged public var rating: String?
    @NSManaged public var summary: String?
    @NSManaged public var type: String?
    @NSManaged public var images: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for images
extension Restaurant {

    @objc(addImagesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToImages(_ value: Images)

    @objc(removeImagesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromImages(_ value: Images)

    @objc(addImages:)
    @NSManaged public func addToImages(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeImages:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromImages(_ values: NSSet)

}





import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Images {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Images> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Images>(entityName: "Images")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var image: Data?
    @NSManaged public var origin: Restaurant?

}






 var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()
    
    func getAssetThumbnail(assets: [PHAsset]) -> [UIImage] {
       
        for asset in assets {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var image = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true
            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                image = result!
                self.arrayOfImages.append(image)
            })
        }
        return arrayOfImages
    }
```

Comment: Would making the relationship "to many" work for you? You could store multiple images which have the same restaurant origin that way.

Comment: @aswath - it is one to many , but i do not know the coredata query to be able to insert images in image entity, which will correspond to id of user from restaurant

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - thanks as i am new to coredata , i ended up using classDefinition codegen option instead of manual , hence i did not get the class Restaurant in my navigator, but when now i try and use code and manual option i get error every where i have used Restaurant keyword used to access this entity, how can i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Restaurant` class will have a function `addToImages` that you can use. So something like this should work

Create a custom init method for `Images`(which should really be named `Image`) to simplify the rest of the code

```
extension Images {
     convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, image: UIImage) {
          self.init(context: context)
          self.id = UUID()
          self.image = image.pngData()
     }
}
```

and then

```
var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()
    
for image in arrayOfImages {
    restaurant.addToImages(Images(context: moc, image: image))
}
```

Or all at once

```
restaurant.addToImages(Set(arrayOfImages.map { Images(context: moc, image: $0 }))
```

In the above code examples `moc` is an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`.

To access the images you can read the `images` attribute of `Restaurant`, for instance like this to get an array of UIImage

```
let imageArray = restaurant.images.map { UIImage(data: $0.image as Data) }
```

Regarding the `image` attribute in `Restaurant`: You can just delete any attributes in the core data model that are not used any more

Comment: thanks, so what will be the use of images entity, will data for image automatically enter it, also how will i be able to retrieve theses images ?i am having no knowledge of coredata hence asking

Comment: so now that i am able to save all the images, currently i use this code to display an image from core data --  if let restaurantImage = restaurant.image {
                                         cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
                                     } ---- but suppose i try and display the second image in the array and use restaurant.image[1], its giving error, what is it that i am doing wrong , thanks

Comment: So now that i saved the data using  for image in arrayOfImages {
                    print("saved")
                    restaurant.image = image.pngData()
                } , i was wondering how do i retrieve this to be able to access a particular image form array if images

Comment: You can access the images using the `images` attribute in the Restaurant class which returns a Set of `Images`.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, thanks but i was running your code now i have compiles classes manually but i keep getting error - No exact matches in call to instance method 'addToImages', this is the function i get in my class -  @objc(addImages:)
    @NSManaged public func addToImages(_ values: NSSet)

Comment: @multiverse convert the array to a Set , `restaurant.addToImages(Set(arrayOfImages.map { $0.pngData() }))`

Comment: i tried but get same error , i updated the question with classes i get when compiling manually , thanks

Comment: also i added method i used to get array of images

Comment: @multiverse Yes of course, such a stupid mistake by me. The array shouldn't contain Data, it should contain `Images` objects instead. I will update the answer

Comment: thanks a lot for your time , just one final issue is that if were to try and fetch the images and display the second image from the array, using the code as provided by you  --  let imageArray = restaurant.images.map { UIImage(data: $0.image as Data) }, i am getting error --- Value of type 'NSSet' has no member 'image'